# Python: import a.b vs from a import b

Tags: python, python-import

The following two statements appear to be equivalent (assuming `b` is a submodule):

```
import a.b as c
```

and

```
from a import b as c
```

Both allow me to refer to `a.b.foo` as `c.foo`.

Which one is preferred?

Comment: Generally, I use the second form if I absolutely have to, but I don't think there's any real consensus here...  Also, generally, I'd prefer if you _didn't_ alias your imports without a good reason (the only "good reason" that I can think of off the top of my head being providing a compatable alternative to something else)

Comment: from a import b as c is preferred!

Comment: They are not equivalent: compare `import itertools.product as c` with `from itertools import product as c`.

Comment: @chepner: `product` is not a submodule. this is not what my question is about.

Comment: @chepner `import itertools.product as c` results in an error as you cannot import anything other than `modules` and `packages` with the `import` syntax, only with `from .. import ..` syntax